# Linux上のOracleDatabaseからWindows環境に向けてexpdpしたい。

Tags: oracle

**実行環境:**
Oracle Linux - Oracle Database 19c
Windows Server 2019

Linux上にOracle Databaseが構築されている環境において
WindowsServerに向けてexpdpでdmpファイルを出力したい。
また、WindowsServer上のdmpファイルをもとにLinuxのDBに
impdpでインポートしたいのですが、可能でしょうか？
方法をご教示頂きたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

可能ではないと思います。
Data Pump(expdp/impdp)はディレクトリオブジェクトで示されたディレクトリ(※)下のダンプファイルを対象とします。※今回のケースではLinux側のディレクトリ

Linux側のディレクトリをWindows側と共有するか、ファイル転送でダンプファイルをやり取りする必要があると思います。

Comment: 「cifs-utils」などを利用してフォルダ共有しなければならないのですね。
ありがとうございます。